# Helper methods and associations with include not working on sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't call the helper methods that should have been generated by sequelize when using belongsTo/hasMany. And I cannot eager load a table.
When trying to run the helper methods I get a message saying there is no such method, and when trying to use findAll with include passing the other table it says that the tables are not associated, please see details below:

models directory:

```
./models
--ticket.js
--category.js
--index.js
```

ticket.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Ticket = sequelize.define('Ticket', {
    // category_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    subject: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    requester_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    requester_email: DataTypes.STRING,
    owner_email: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['opened', 'in progress', 'closed']
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Ticket.belongsTo(models['Category']);
        Ticket.hasMany(models['Interaction']);
      }
    }
  });

  return Ticket;
};
```

category.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Category.hasMany(models['Ticket']);
      }
    }
  });
  return Category;
};
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Then I create constants for the models:

```
const models = require('../models'),
    Ticket = models['Ticket'],
    Category = models['Category'];
```

When trying to call Ticket.getCategory(), like below:

```
Ticket.findById(req.params.ticket_id).then((ticket) => {
        ticket.getCategory().then((category)=>{
            ticket['category'] = category;
            res.json(ticket);
        });
    });
```

I get:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `subject`, `description`, `requester_name`, `requester_email`, `owner_email`, `status`, `created_at`, `updated_at` FROM `Tickets` AS `Ticket` WHERE `Ticket`.`id` = '1';
Unhandled rejection TypeError: ticket.getCategory is not a function
```

If I try to use eager loading, like below:

```
Ticket.findAll({where:{id:req.params.ticket_id},include:[Category]}).then((ticket) => {
    res.json(ticket);
});
```

I get:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Category is not associated to Ticket!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your sequelize version?

Comment: "sequelize": "^4.2.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you are using seqielize ^4.2.0, which is major update API has little changes.'

In version 4 you shouldn't add class methods through `classMethods` object, instead you should do this.

```
var Ticket = sequelize.define('Ticket', {
    // category_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    subject: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    requester_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    requester_email: DataTypes.STRING,
    owner_email: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['opened', 'in progress', 'closed']
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true,
});

Ticket.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Ticket.belongsTo(models['Category']);
    Ticket.hasMany(models['Interaction']);
};
```

You can read how to upgrade from sequelize 3 to 4 [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html)

Comment: Thanks Aren! I fixed this a few hours ago looking at their nodejs-example, took me sometime to think of this, came here to answer and found your answer. This solved the problem! Didn't know about the changes from 3 to 4 though, thanks!

Comment: Welcome sir! Glad that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your associations are not completely done. You need to specify a foreign key. For example:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Ticket = sequelize.define('Ticket', {
    //blablabla
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // here specify which are your foreign keys
        // category_id is just to illustrate
        Ticket.belongsTo(models['Category'], {foreignKey: category_id});
        Ticket.hasMany(models['Interaction'], {foreignKey: something_id});
      }
    }
  });

  return Ticket;
};
```

This also needs to be done in the counterpart, Category and Interaction in this case. Then you will be able to use the sequelize magic

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I've have read that that is the default foreignKey, but just to make sure I have added it, but got the same result. As you can see I have created the associations on category (hasMany) and on ticket (belongsTo). The foreignKey should only be added to the belongsTo association, correct? Please ignore the Interaction asociation.

Comment: I always add them both ways (belongsTo and hasMany). Don't know if one is not mandatory. Also, have you defined the field? In your ticket definition you have subject, description, etc, but I don't see a category_id defined. May be that the problem?